# trouble install phpunit on windows 7, wamp server

Tags: windows, installation, phpunit, pear

I have try install phpunit on windows 7, but i have issue like this:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13>pear channel-discover components.ez.no
Adding Channel "components.ez.no" succeeded
Discovery of channel "components.ez.no" succeeded

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13>pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is already initialized

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13>pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
Channel "pear.symfony.com" is already initialized

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13>pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
downloading PHPUnit-3.7.9.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.7.9.tgz (116,997 bytes)
.........................done: 116,997 bytes
Could not delete pear\phpunit, cannot rename pear\.tmpphpunit
ERROR: commit failed
```

I don't know whats going on, I have search for hours but cannot find solution.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Haven't see this error before but it seems to be a permission issue.

Try running the cmd prompt with admin privileges and use

```
pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

in case anything else goes wrong now due to caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

you need to open your command line window as administrator.

see instructions here.
http://beagile.biz/php-pear-package-install-issues-on-windows/